# Putting a link in a php/html table which uses mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

can anyone help?

Apologies if I'm being stupid but I'm very new to this and I don't really know what I'm doing...

I have generated a table which uses php to get data from a mysql database, but I want to put an extra column at the end (of every row) which contains a link. The link will be to further details about that entry.

The code I have which displays the table is as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='5'>
<tr>
<th>order_no</th>
<th>ord_date</th>
<th>est_completion_date</th>
<th>status</th>
<th>invoice_date</th>
<th>inv_amount</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>fName</th>
<th>lName</th>
</tr>";

// -- Use 'while' to check each row in $result in turn:
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['order_no'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ord_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['est_completion_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['invoice_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['inv_amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['fName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Like I say, I'm a beginner. Basically I am reasonably happy (using the code above) in making html tables which display the results of a mysql query. However I need the users to be able to click on rows/cells in order link to other tables.

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: What are you  struggling with exactly? You can `echo` whatever HTML you need.

Comment: Can I suggest that you accept an answer here? You've basically asked the same question twice, and in both cases you received good answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PHP forms in mysql queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098031/using-php-forms-in-mysql-queries)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<table border='5'>
<tr>
<th>order_no</th>
<th>ord_date</th>
<th>est_completion_date</th>
<th>status</th>
<th>invoice_date</th>
<th>inv_amount</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>fName</th>
<th>lName</th>
<!-- extra column here -->
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['order_no'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ord_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['est_completion_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['invoice_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['inv_amount'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lName'] . "</td>";
    // add link here
    echo "<td><a href=''>link</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Please note:** You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Maybe use `'` for the link string at least or escape the `"` in the string?

Comment: Matt, another question. The code you've given above works for linking to a URL. However if I want to link to a page which runs a mysql query based on the order_no of the row being clicked, how do I do that? The code in Anoop's answer below doesn't seem to be working (i.e. when I put that in my page and refresh the page is blank).

Comment: @user1620419 just add the order_no to the querystring of the link: `echo "<a href='somepage.php?order=$order_no'>...";` You can retrieve the value using the `$_GET` superglobal: `$_GET['order_no']`.

Comment: I've tried it with echo "<td>" . "<a href="orderConsistsOf.php?key=$row['order_no']">View More</a>" . "</td>"; (as below), when I save that and refresh I only get a blank page. I have just tried echo "<td><a href='orderConsistsOf.php?order_no=$order_no'></td>"; (is this what you just suggested?) which does give me an extra column in the table, but no links. Sorry for all the super-basic questions - its confusing when you don't know how...

Comment: Try concatenating the variable value into the string, rather than forcing PHP to parse it and "figure out" if it's a variable. Obviously, if you never define `$order_no` nothing will print (clearly, this was just an example - `$order_no` should have been replaced with whatever variable you use to store the order number). Try this instead: `echo "<td><a href='orderConsistsOf.php?order_no=" . $row['order_no'] . "'>View More</a></td>";`

Comment: FYI, if you want to add the value of an array index in a double-quote encapsulated string, you have to use curly braces: E.G.: `echo "The value of the array at index 'myIndex' is {$array['myIndex']}";`

Comment: Matt seeing as your comments helped so much would you mind taking a look at a follow-on question if you have a moment? Its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164078/using-multiple-mysql-queries-in-the-same-php-db-connection-plus-get

Answer (score 0):

try this. add a column. It will link to another page "view_more_details.php". To identify rows uniquely, pass a unique id with this link. Here I passed order_no. In the
 "view_more_details.php" page, you can select this value by using $_GET['key']

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='5'>
<tr>
<th>order_no</th>
<th>ord_date</th>
<th>est_completion_date</th>
<th>status</th>
<th>invoice_date</th>
<th>inv_amount</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>fName</th>
<th>lName</th>
<th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>";

// -- Use 'while' to check each row in $result in turn:
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['order_no'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ord_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['est_completion_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['invoice_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['inv_amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['fName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<a href="view_more_details.php?key=$row['order_no']">View More</a>" . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hi Anoop - thanks for this. Just to be clear (like I say, I'm pretty ignorant with this stuff) can I then use $_GET in a mysql query on the 'view_more_details.php' (or whatever I call it) page to filter results? Is this similar to $_POST (which I have used elsewhere thanks to advice from these pages)?

Comment: Hi Anoop - when I put the code above in my page and refresh the page is blank. Do you know why this could be? Do I need to include action="view_more_details.php" method="get"> anywhere as with forms or is this implied by the code you've given?

Comment: please check whether your database table is empty. There is no need for action page for this. You can get value in view_more_details.php by the following code. $value=$_GET['key']; . Then you will get the order no of the item. Then you can execute queries by using that key.