# Using PHP forms in mysql queries

Tags: php, html, forms

Another (basic) question here. I need to know how to use html forms to filter the results of a  mysql query using PHP. I have been looking at w3schools and I can see how using $_POST on one page can output to another page. But I cannot see exactly how to put the $_POST into my query.  For example I have one page as below:

```
<form action="orderlist.php" method="post">
OrderNo: <input type="int" name="order_no" />
<input type="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is a page where the user can enter an order_no and click submit, which links to the 'orderslist.php' page. On that page I have the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='5'>
<tr>
<th>order_no</th>
<th>ord_date</th>
<th>est_completion_date</th>
<th>status</th>
<th>invoice_date</th>
<th>inv_amount</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>fName</th>
<th>lName</th>
</tr>";

// -- Use 'while' to check each row in $result in turn:
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['order_no'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ord_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['est_completion_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['invoice_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['inv_amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['fName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

This outputs everything from 'orders' into a table, but I want it to only output the row with the order_no that the user entered on the previous page. How do I do this? Is it something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_no = $_POST[order_no]");
```

Thank a lot

Comment: Try: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_no = " . $_POST["order_no"]);`

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: @andrewsi dude, that's WAY open to injection attacks. BAD!

Comment: Where is this site hosted?  I have an order I want to lookup.  Specifically, order number `5; drop table orders;` :D

Comment: Seriously, @user1620419, before you go any further you should implement PDO or mysqli. It will make your life infinitely easier.

Comment: [Have you heard of little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: yep that should work fine, is it ?

Comment: @Matt - I walked past a diner this morning called Bobby's Table, and spent the next few minutes explaining why I started sniggering.

Comment: @andrewsi "snigger" sounds like a term no one should use. I thought the term was "snicker"

Comment: @Matt - snigger would seem to be the UK variant of snicker. So that's the new thing I've learned today.

Comment: @andrewsi haha removing the 's' would get you a one-way ticket to a hospital here.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, you should switch to PDO or mysqli -- the `mysql_*` functions are in the process of deprecation.

On to your question: yes, that's how you do it, with a `WHERE` clause. However, it is very (very very very) insecure to concatenate a variable directly out of `$_POST` without sanitation.

That said, at a minimum you should do this:

```
mysql_query('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_no = '.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[order_no]));
```

Another thing... don't use `SELECT *`. You should always list the columns you expect to get from the database -- that way, if there is a problem (like the columns have changed), the query can let you know. With `SELECT *` you get back a magical grab-bag of data -- you have no idea what it is, and more importantly, if it has the values your code relies on.

So, putting it together:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", '-username-', '-password-');
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT 
        `order_no`,
        `ord_date`,
        `est_completion_date`,
        `status`,
        `invoice_date`,
        `inv_amount`,
        `name`,
        `fName`,
        `lName`
    FROM 
        orders 
    WHERE 
        order_no = :order_no
');
$sth->execute(array(':order_no'=>$_POST[order_no]));
while ($order= $sth->fetch()) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->order_no . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->ord_date . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->est_completion_date . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->status . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->invoice_date . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->inv_amount . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->name . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->fName . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $order->lName . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Edit**: One last note, the input you're using is not valid; `type="int"` is not a recognized input type. [Here's a list of types for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#input-control-types), and [a list for HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html#input):

As you can see, HTML 5 does have a new input type "number". It is not fully adopted, but if you wanted to use it:

`<input type="number" name="order_no" />`

Be aware, however, that not all browsers will restrict the input to numeric: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

**Documentation**

- mySql `SELECT` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
- `mysql_query` (**DEPRECATED**) - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
- PDO - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- `PDO::prepare` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
- `PDOStatement::fetch` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
- `PDOStatement::execute` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: I don't think answers get any more comprehensive than this.

Comment: @user1620419 Glad to help! Be sure to select an answer as "selected" (click the green checkmark) :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$orderNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order_no']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_no = $orderNumber");
```

This takes the value of `$_POST['order_no']` and somewhat sanitizes it. You then apply the value of `$orderNumber` to MySQL.

However, you're much better off using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Both protect you (if used correctly) from SQL injection. Currenly, your code is VERY prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Beat me to it; this should do it

Comment: `strip_tags`? Of all the possible string functions, I don't understand why you'd advocate using that one. Why not actually sanitize it with `mysql_real_escape_string`? Why not `addslashes`? `intval`? `strip_tags`, might as well use `highlight_string` for all the good it would do. -1

Comment: @Chris - You're right, my mistake. I used the wrong function. Edit made.

Answer (score 1):

Without injection vulnerability (require 'mysql_connect' before) :

```
if(isset($_POST['order_no']))
{
    $orderNo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order_no']);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_no = $orderNo");

    echo "<table border='5'>";
    echo "  <tr>";
    echo "    <th>order_no</th>";
    echo "    <th>ord_date</th>";
    echo "    <th>est_completion_date</th>";
    echo "    <th>status</th>";
    echo "    <th>invoice_date</th>";
    echo "    <th>inv_amount</th>";
    echo "    <th>name</th>";
    echo "    <th>fName</th>";
    echo "    <th>lName</th>";
    echo "  </tr>";

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="9">Order not found</td></tr>';
    }
    else
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['order_no'] . "</td>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['ord_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['est_completion_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['invoice_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['inv_amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['fName'] . "</td>";
            echo "  <td>" . $row['lName'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: What if order numbers are alpha-numeric?

Comment: Updated. He did not use quotes in his query, so I thought that it was a number.

Comment: Probably is... just sayin' :)

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be something like this:

```
<form action="orderlist.php" method="post">
    OrderNo: <input type="text" name="order_no" />
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

To get any value that is **typed by user** in the form you should use `type="text"`.
There is nothing like `type="int"` in standard HTML.

Don't get confused, the Input TYPE in HTML is not the same as one you use in Programming languages to declare Data type. Here TYPE is just to let the browser know that its a text field / Radio Button etc.
To understand *Valid Input Types* better read this [w3.org recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-type-INPUT) on HTML forms.

On `orderlist.php` you can query to retrieve the required data:

```
if(isset($_POST['order_no'])) {
    $orderNo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order_no']);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_no = $orderNo");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //code to print table.   
    }
}
```

#### Note:

This type of code is Vulnerable to easy attacks, and it is never recommended to put user input directly into SQL query, it should always be filtered first.